# resultCode == RESULT_OK is not working in redmi note3

Tags: android

Hi I want to capture image and do some opration for that image in my next activity.I have tried to run the below code in Samsung and Moto G and its working fine.When I tried same code with redmi note3,after Clicking right mark it is coming to the same activity.How to solve this? This is my code:

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(originalFile);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No camera app found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Bitmap imageData = null;
            if (resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try
                    {
                        BitmapFactory.Options bitopt=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        imageData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bitopt);
                        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imageData);

                        Intent i = new Intent(this, Image_R.class);
                        i.putExtra("imageUri", tempUri.toString());
                        startActivityForResult(i, 3);
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to save image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            }
            }
```

Comment: Debug your onActivityResult method and check what is wrong and at which step then post it for better help

Comment: @Vickyexpert When I run this code resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK getting resultCode=0 for redmi and moto resultCode=-1.Also after that it is not going to try block in redmi mobile.

Comment: this code is in fragment or in activity ?

Comment: @Vishal Patoliya It is Activity

Comment: put your activity defination code which is belongs to manifest file

Comment: @Amshu which permissions are given in manifest file ??

Comment: @Vishal Patoliya Probem was with using Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(originalFile);ntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri); in redmi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123338/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-amshu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this:--

```
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: what is MyFileContentProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `activity` tag inside your `Manifest` file.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

It will not let your current activity to destroy and re-create so you will get the result.

And if this doesn't work make sure that your Device is not on power/battery saving mode.
RedMi devices with active power/battery saving mode cause previous activity to lose it's state and when coming back for result it will call `onCreate` again so you won't get the true result.

Comment: I  tried with that code and also power/battery saving mode is off.Still it is not calling the next activity.

Comment: As @Vickyexpert said you should debug your onActivityResult and check what's actually wrong. Then edit the question or comment.
Happy to help.

Comment: When I run this code resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK getting  resultCode=0 for redmi and moto resultCode=-1.Also after that it is not going to try block in redmi mobile.

Comment: What about requestCode ? Are they returning as expected ?

Comment: Have you checked 'don't keep activities' in developer options ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123306/discussion-between-amshu-and-mann).

Comment: @Mann he is forgot to add i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);